# Get text inside parentheses

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string that contains the following:

```
test (alpha)
```

I want to get the text inside the parentheses so that I only have `alpha`. This can be achieved using a regular expression such as `\(([^)]*)\)`. Is there an easier way?

Comment: string.IndexOf and string.Substring, but it requires more lines of code

Comment: By using a simpler regex perhaps `\((\w+)\)` or by splitting `"test (alpha)".Split('(', ')')[1]`

Comment: by easier, do you mean non-regex way?

Comment: In this context I meant in less lines of code.

Comment: @JHarley1 Then would it be possible to see the number of lines of code you have currently? The current 'code' you show has only one line...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is an easy one. If you don't want to create two indexes that is, if you want to achieve this without any capturing group then you could use lookaround based regex like below.

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(?<=\()[^()]*(?=\))");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gQ3kS4/26)

- `(?<=\()` Positive lookbehind, which asserts that the match must be preceded by an opening paranthesis `(`.
- `[()]*` Matches any character but not of `(` or `)` zero or more times.
- `(?=\))` Positive lookahead which asserts that the match must be followed by a `)` closing paranthesis.

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/Pu8FFI)

Comment: This looks much easier ;-)

Comment: Had a Google around - not really sure how this would look in code? does it use .Regex?

Comment: I don't think this one looks easy for a beginner in regex...

Comment: @nhahtdh i already mentioned that the op's regex is much more easier to understand.

Comment: @nhahtdh Avinash Raj Hit the three major points. When, what and where. The rest is [reading](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Answer (score 1):

A non regex solution.

```
string test = "test (alpha)";
int posFirst = test.IndexOf("(");
int posLast = test.LastIndexOf(")");
if(posFirst>= 0 && posLast >= 0)
{
    string result = test.Substring(posFirst + 1, (posLast  - posFirst -1));
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

This will take everything that is inside the first open paren to the last close one.
If you want to get only to the first close paren then change the extraction of posLast using IndexOf